# UIView.animateWithDuration does not work when called from delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, animatewithduration

I am using the following function to move self.view to the specified x axis:

```
func shiftMainContainer(#targetPosition: CGFloat, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)! = nil) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.view.frame.origin.x = 300
        println("View should shift")
        }, completion: completion)
}
```

When I call this function from an @IBAction button in the same view, it works, but when I call it using a delegate method from a sub-view, nothing happens. I know that the delegate works because the println prints the text like it should, but the view isn't shifted like in the first scenario.

Does calling it from a subview delegate make a difference?

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've been banging my head on the wall for this for the better part of the day now.

### Update:-

Manage to reproduce the problem in a new blank project. Check it out here:

https://github.com/EugeneTeh/DelegateAnimateTest

Comment: is the self.view in your code representing the desired view itself?

Comment: Yes, it is. That's why I double checked with the IBAction button to make sure.

Comment: Did u try using self.view.bounds instead of frame?

Comment: I just did, similar results though the positioning is different.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it works fine for me when I added `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`

```
func shiftMainContainer(#targetPosition: CGFloat, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)! = nil) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.view.frame.origin.x = 300
        println("View should shift")
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: completion)
}
```